# Is it possible to manipulate PDF with forms via PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I spend a day for digging possible way to manipulate PDF's with forms and still in search. I got PDF, where user can fill some data, save and send to me. The problem is some users didn't know about Acrobat reader and dont't know how to install it. Plus some users are mobile. I try all possible ways - jsPDF lib, FPDF + FPDI, but all this libs work very bad with forms.

Any suggestion how to solve it?

UPDATE. I can't just set php action for PDF form, I also need some action outside PDF.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/filling-pdf-forms-pdftk-php/

Comment: Thank you, this is good solution. I use php-pdftk for this - it works great. But there is some problem - I also need to add image to PDF. I do it with FPDI, but FPDI flatten PDF, and after all form fields not available to typing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve this issue. I use [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) class as wrapper for pdftk. This class let me fill form with fillForm(). And I use stamp() and multiStamp() methods of class for add image to filled PDF. I create PDF with image and use them as a stamp.